# How to force firefox to use the cache?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I have firefox 27 on windows.

I browse a lot of picture boards with a slow bandwidth so it is very handy not to load the images each time I click on a thread already viewed.
Iron does use the cache  properly, but firefox reloads everything  each time.
I have browser.cache.disk.enable;true and enough disk space setup.

Comment: What's the `browser.cache.check_doc_frequency` value set to in `about:config`?

Comment: it is valued to 3

Comment: That's the default value. The preference controls how often to check for a newer version of a cached page. Possible values are `0-3`: `0` - check for a new version of a page once per session; `1` - check for a new version every time a page is loaded; `2` - never checks for a new version - always load the page from cache; `3` - check for a new version when the page is out of date. Make sure the `browser.cache.memory.enable` preference is set to `true`, then change the `browser.cache.check_doc_frequency` value. Clear the cache, restart Firefox, and see whether it makes any difference.